# libc6 (dependency of a package I'm trying to install) requires newer kernel, I can't upgrade though

Tags: debian, kernel, aptitude

There. It occured multiple times to me already, that packages I tried to install (e.g. ngircd or make) have a dependency called libc6, which required kernel version 3.2 however. I cannot upgrade my kernel, as I'm owning a VPS which runs on OpenVZ. Is there any way for me to still somehow install those packages which depend on libc6?

Comment: Could you add install command and its output?

Comment: To install, I use `apt install ngircd`, `apt install make` depends on what I want to install, and those packages have libc6 as a dependency so it tries to install that. I then get a colored error window (in the terminal) saying that my kernel is outdated. I cannot give you the exact output at the moment, as I somehow broke my whole apt command so it gives me thousand of error lines. I'll reset the server and give you the output tomorrow.

Comment: I understood that much, but for those trying to help, an actual copy/paste from the command and the output could add lots of useful information. Let's wait then.

Comment: Which version of Debian are you running?  If you are running Debian 10, it should come with a recent version of `libc6` and let those packages install (unless the provider did some `libc6` workaround in their Debian images).  OpenVZ with 2.6.x kernels are really old and looks to be unsupported after November 2019.  Your provider should upgrade to a more recent version OpenVZ, or you could change providers.

Comment: I was using Debian 9. My host doesn't have Debian 10 available. I already messaged my host, but they said that upgrading the kernel on their servers wouldn't be possible and I should switch to KVM Servers, which would cost me ~13€ instead of 5€ and is definetly too much.